# Sudoku solver not returning a completed board

Tags: python, sudoku

```
import numpy as np




def row(board,x,y):
    """Takes in a board and x y coordinates and returns all
   the row candidates"""
    numbers = np.arange(1,10)
    missing = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number not in board[x]:
            missing.append(number)
        else:
            continue
    return missing

def column(board,x,y):
    """Takes an incomplete board and returns all the
   column candidates"""
    numbers = np.arange(1,10)
    missing = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number not in board[:,y]:
            missing.append(number)
        else:
            continue
    return missing

def box(board,x,y):
    """Takes an incomplete board, coordinates and returns the
   box wise candidates"""
    numbers = list(range(1,10))
    missing = []
    box1 = np.array([board[0,0:3],board[1,0:3],board[2,0:3]])
    box2 = np.array([board[0,3:6],board[1,3:6],board[2,3:6]])
    box3 = np.array([board[0,6:10],board[1,6:10],board[2,6:10]])
    box4 = np.array([board[3,0:3],board[4,0:3],board[5,0:3]])
    box5 = np.array([board[3,3:6],board[4,3:6],board[5,3:6]])
    box6 = np.array([board[3,6:10],board[4,6:10],board[5,6:10]])
    box7 = np.array([board[6,0:3],board[7,0:3],board[8,0:3]])
    box8 = np.array([board[6,3:6],board[7,3:6],board[8,3:6]])
    box9 = np.array([board[6,6:10],board[7,6:10],board[8,6:10]])

    condition1 = 0<=x<=2 and 0<=y<=2
    condition2 = 0<=x<=2 and 3<=y<=5
    condition3 = 0<=x<=2 and 6<=y<=8
    condition4 = 3<=x<=5 and 0<=y<=2
    condition5 = 3<=x<=5 and 3<=y<=5
    condition6 = 3<=x<=5 and 6<=y<=8
    condition7 = 6<=x<=8 and 0<=y<=2
    condition8 = 6<=x<=8 and 3<=y<=5
    condition9 = 6<=x<=8 and 6<=y<=8

    if condition1:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box1:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition2:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box2:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition3:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box3:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition4:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box4:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition5:
        for number in numbers:
            if number in box5:
                continue
            else:
                missing.append(number)

    if condition6:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box6:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition7:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box7:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition8:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box8:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    if condition9:
        for number in numbers:
            if number not in box9:
                missing.append(number)
            else:
                continue

    return missing

def sudsolver(board):
    """Give it a board andt it will solve it for your using the functions defined above."""
    newboard = board.copy()
    for index,n in np.ndenumerate(board):
        if board[index] == 0:
            x = index[0]
            y = index[1]
            boxsolution = box(newboard,x,y)
            columnsolution = column(newboard,x,y)
            rowsolution = row(newboard,x,y)

            if len(boxsolution) or len(columnsolution) or len(rowsolution) < 1:
                for number in boxsolution:
                    if number in columnsolution and number in rowsolution:
                        newboard[index] = number
                    else:
                        continue

        else:
            continue

    return newboard

testboard = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0,   3, 7, 0,   0, 5, 6],
    [5, 0, 0,   0, 1, 0,   9, 7, 0],
    [0, 6, 0,   9, 8, 0,   3, 4, 0],

    [0, 0, 7,   0, 0, 2,   0, 8, 0],
    [0, 0, 9,   0, 3, 0,   6, 0, 0],
    [0, 5, 0,   8, 0, 0,   2, 0, 0],

    [0, 7, 5,   0, 6, 9,   0, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 8,   0, 2, 0,   0, 0, 5],
    [2, 9, 0,   0, 5, 8,   0, 0, 0]
])

pleasework = sudsolver(testboard)
```

I have created different functions to check the solutions of a given cell, however, when the board is returned from the sudsolver function, the board still has a few 0's in it.

The board which I am using is called testboard and I have been assured that it is possible to solve.

I cannot think of why this is and how to solve it. Any help would be great.

Comment: How did you test the individual functions?  i usually import my code in a python shell and test by calling functions with a range of arguments.

Comment: I cannot have a solution but the issue is `newboard[index] = number` is done within for loop which results in always take the highest number in `boxsolution` as a solution but sometimes highest number is incorrect for the cell. With the incorrect solution in the cell, another cell you get "0" does not have any common solution across box, column, and row.

Comment: @Emma thanks for the response, it seems that is the issue, however I think of a way to overcome this.

Comment: Just an improvement. You can remove all `else: continue`. They are all unnecessary in these cases.